# Overfilled oil by 1 quart in a Chevy Spark

Tags: chevrolet, oil, spark

I have about a quart/liter of extra oil in a 2016 Chevy Spark.

Will it be OK to drive it? I don’t want to damage the engine. I’ve read so far that 1 quart isn’t much but for such a small car I’m wondering if it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For peace of mind, go to a good workshop and they will have a tube that can be put down the dipstick hole which will then remove the excess (it sucks the oil out).

That amount may or may not be a problem - depends on the shape of the sump and other factors.

If you leave it it may be fine, but for the 10 minutes and possibly small charge just get it done.